# How to connect to expo via private tunnel (not ngrok)

Tags: ssh, expo

I have the problem that at work I can not connect via network to expo, so I need to use tunnel, which is fine. However sometimes the tunnel is really slow destroying any developer expierience.

Since I can also host expo locally on localhost I had the idea of simply ssh-tunneling to a remote server that has an open port.

my remote host runs ubuntu

so i SSH there like so:

```
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:19000:0.0.0.0:19000 user@ip
```

in order for this to work i also added

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

to my   /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...

```
sudo netstat -plutn
```

shows me

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20183/2
```

so accepting requests (i also tried to forward port 19001 to get something back when i enter it in the browser which worke fine)

However when i enter:
exp://serverip:19000 into the expo client on my android phone he can't connect.
Any ideas on help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Expo uses multiple ports 19000, 19001, and 19002. So you will need to forward all of these.

e.g.

```
$ ssh -f -N -R 19000:localhost:19000 user@ip
$ ssh -f -N -R 19001:localhost:19001 user@ip
$ ssh -f -N -R 19002:localhost:19002 user@ip
```

Also, you can set the `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` environment variable to use the remote host.

```
$ export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME="ip"
$ expo start
```